# Are Folk Tales acceptable sources?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

Folktales are stories passed down through generations, mainly by telling. Some of these stories are genuine and some are made up stories. But some legends of lesser known temples can be found in these Folk tales. So, are Folk Tales acceptable sources?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you make clear that the story is a folktale, and you provide a source for it (like a book or website giving the folktale), it's absolutely fine to discuss folktales on this site.  (Of course, if the question is asking for a scriptural basis for a story, then folktales wouldn't suffice; a lot of my questions begin with "What scriptures".)  By the way, in the case of temples they usually have Sthala Puranas, so if possible a Sthala Puranas is often the best source to cite for the story of a temple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folktale are acceptable as an answer till you mention it that way and provide essential source for it too. Source can be a temple inscription, book etc.

But if question explicitly asking for scripture, then its not acceptable. It can be acceptable in the case where you can proof that its not present in any scripture and you are presenting an answer with a folktale with mentioning that its not part of any scripture.

Comment: What if source is some blog or website?

Comment: @TheDestroyer If its a folk tale then its not going to part of any scripture, so there source can't be fully reliable. I do think blog/website ,ight work for them.

Comment: @TheDestroyer http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/597/277